# Importação de módulos com Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, babel, módulo-python

Como posso fazer **import** de bibliotecas, como por exemplo, estava pesquisando e achei o *[Babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/)* para fazer internacionalização de datas, mas não sei como importar essa biblioteca?

Answer (score 3):

Faça através da palavra reservada `import` ou `from modulo import Classe`. por exemplo:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 6, 21, 57, 23, 947736)
>>> import os
>>> os.name
'posix'
```

Veja na [documentação oficial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) do python

No caso do Babel, na página da biblioteca tem um exemplo

```
>>> from babel.dates import format_datetime
>>> print format_datetime(locale='ru_RU')
26 июля 2013 г., 15:48:18
```

http://babel.pocoo.org/

Answer (score 2):

Acho que você não está falando da instalação. Tem na [documentação](http://babel.pocoo.org/docs/installation/).

O padrão para importação no código é isto:

```
from babel import *
```

Isto importará toda biblioteca Babel. Mas pode escolher só o que interessa:

```
from babel import Locale
```

Ou pode importar vários membros. E pode fazer através de um sub-módulo:

```
from babel.dates import format_date, format_datetime, format_time
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/Import2.py).

Neste caso `dates` é um sub-módulo dentro do módulo `babel`.

Tudo isto eu peguei na [documentação](http://babel.pocoo.org/docs/). Acho que é o melhor caminho para aprender a usar a biblioteca.

Se quiser estudar o sistema de módulos do Python a [documentação está aqui](https://docs.python.org/3.9/tutorial/modules.html). E [sobre a importação](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/import.html).

Comment: Peço perdão se estiver sendo muito ignorante agora mas, o que eu fiz foi baixar no site do babel o zip e depois dele baixado eu não sei onde colocar o arquivo e quando eu tentei fazer essa linha: `from babel import *` ele acusa que não encontrou.

Comment: É , realmente você está muito crú e sua pergunta não fala sobre isto. Fora isto, você tem que dar mais detalhes do que está fazendo. Programação é precisão. Se você não conseguir descrever o problema de forma que eu possa entender, não vou poder ajudar. Você digitou isto onde? Como executou? Que erro deu? Eu sequer achei este `zip` que você falou no site deles. De qualquer forma, na documentação tem como faz a instalação.

Comment: O que pode estar acontecendo é que você instalou a biblioteca para uma versão do python e está tentando importar os módulos em outra. Quando for instalar, lembre-se de usar pip3 para se certificar de que será instalada no python3, se houver mais de uma versão de python3 na máquina é preciso ficar atento. Já aconteceu isso comigo ao usar o pygame. O pip3 instalou no python 3.4 e eu estava tentando abrir no 3.8. Então recebia a mensagem de que não havia biblioteca com aquele nome. Mas sem mais especificações fica difícil de saber se é realmente esse o problema